# Ember View - HTML Entities escaped on second set

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I want to render a HTML entity as value into an input field, e.g. m².

For simple demonstration purposes I have tried it out with a view representing the input field, but the standard input helper has the same behavior. The initial rendering works fine, but if the bound value is updated, then suddenly the superscript value is escaped. Thus **m²** changes to **&sup3;**, it should be **m³**.

**Here you can see the code in action:**

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vifup/3/edit

I find it strange that the set call in init works fine, but the update on click does not work.

Is this a bug and are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself. I think the issue arises when setting the value via jQuery. jQuery seems to escape the HTML-Entities before setting them using $.val(). Ember seems to use $.val() in the background.

The simple yet not very nice solution I found is explained here:
http://www.objectpartners.com/2012/07/10/dynamic-html-entities-in-form-inputs/

In short, set the new value containing HTML-Entities to a temporary DOM node as html and retrieve this html again using $.html(). Then set it for the input using $.val()

```
var new_value = $('<div></div>').html('m&sup2;').html();
$('input').val(new_value);
```